# Publishing the result of a research related to development of Mathematica

Tags: mathlink-or-wstp, education

We are developing a library in c language by using WSTP for Mathematica. Do you know a journal for publishing our results?

Comment: Doesn't Wolfram have a Mathematica Journal? I think its more something cool the business does than a great academic journal (?) but it's a neat place to show off Mathematica-related projects.

Comment: See the [Mathematica Journal](http://www.mathematica-journal.com/).

Comment: @C.E. I want a journal which has an impact factor and a JSR factor.

Comment: Perhaps the *Journal of Software Engineering*:  https://scialert.net/current.php?issn=1819-4311

Comment: [This is actually out of scope for this particular forum.] I'd expect a suitable journal to be one that is relevant to the usage domain of the C library, more than anything else.